# Hadoop cannot access /logs/. in secure mode

Tags: security, hadoop, kerberos

I am using hadoop-2.6.0 and enabled security with kerberos. All working fine. But i am unable to access the logs files from browser. It shows

```
Problem accessing /logs/. Reason:

User babu is unauthorized to access this page.
```

I tried with all users but no luck.

Can anyone help me how to authorize any user to access log files?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't access the logs directly in the FS, access is restricted to the NM user and the yarn group. Use the log-aggregation service to retrieve/view logs. See [Simplifying user-logs management and access in YARN](http://hortonworks.com/blog/simplifying-user-logs-management-and-access-in-yarn/).

Comment: I could access the logs in the browser under utilities tab in hostname:50070 without security. But when i enable security i couldn't access.

Comment: Your comment adds nothing new. Of course access permissions are involved in securing the cluster, don't you think so?

Comment: I hope these logs can be access by some particular group of users or by superuser. But none of the user can access it. So how i view the audit logs from any other machine with namenode ip address?

Comment: Use the [HistoryServer REST API](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs/HistoryServerRest.html)

Comment: I am not asking about to view the user logs of completed application of MR job. I am asking about to view the hdfs Audit logging. Is this same as the application log? As i am new to this concept, hope i am asking the question correctly.

Comment: The is entirely up to how the HDFS permissions for `/logs` were configured. The message is clear: `User babu is unauthorized to access this page.`. Grant yourself access, or have an admin grant you access. http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsPermissionsGuide.html

Comment: Yes i did all these things already. But still a superuser itself can't access the audit log. It showing "User is unauthorized to access this page". No user can access it. user "babu" has full permission and it is the superuser.

Comment: If it gets access denied is no [super-user](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsPermissionsGuide.html). What are the permissions and the owner/group on `/logs`?

Comment: Thanks. [superuser](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsPermissionsGuide.html#The_Super-User) is the one who starts the namenode. user "babu" only started the namenode and he can access all folders in the hdfs but not others. It might be some other acl properties to access the /logs/.