# Couldn't view logs page in native UI as logged in as super user

Tags: hadoop, kerberos, kerberos-delegation

I am not able to view the logs file in hadoop admin UI,even am logged with super user credentials.

Please find the details below:
Open native hadoop UI with super user credentials ,I can clearly view the UI page,at same time same super user credentials am not able to view the logs page of native UI page.

Please find the link which I used to view the logs page:
https:///mylapn:50470/logs/

**Error which I get from native UI is,**

Problem accessing /logs/. Reason:
 User john is unauthorized to access this page.

Please suggest how to view logs page and  any necessary to set any configurations.,please find the attached image;

Thanks,
Mathes.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOBMU.png)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30231084/hadoop-cannot-access-logs-in-secure-mode